# LinkedIn post inspector encountering server error on https URL

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

Inspecting a given URL in the LinkedIn post inspector returns the following ingestion feedback:

```
Error   We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.
```

The URL redirect trail shows:

```
1   0 undefined     https://example.com
```

I inspected URLs of both the production domain (https) and a staging sub-domain (http) on the same server (with identical html, needless to say). The LinkedIn scraper is able to fetch all metadata from the http sub-domain but not the https domain which leads me to believe the problem might be related to SSL authentication between the site and LinkedIn.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and can either confirm my suspicion or point me in a direction?

As a sidenote, both the facebook share debugger and the twitter card validator are able to fetch all metadata on all of the tested URLs via both protocols.

Ronald Werkhoven asked the same question here:
[Validating link in post-inspector linkedin in gives server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332742/validating-link-in-post-inspector-linkedin-in-gives-server-error/53171844?noredirect=1#comment93233637_53171844)
Checking the URL he provided in the LinkedIn post inspector does not throw any errors, so apparently he was able to fix the problem.
Would you, Ronald, mind sharing how you were able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I don't have control over the server my client's website is running on. However, Ronald Werkhoven finally answered his own question in more detail in the original thread which gives a much better understanding of the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

one thing i know is that linkedin has crawler issues with the crawlers they use for og. i do not know if they use those crawlers with the post inspector aswell. but that could definitly cause such a issue if they did.

beneath i quoted the response of the linkedin team. so i do not know if there will be a fix anytime soon if these problems are related.

> Thanks for reporting your issue. We've confirmed the problem you reported. After careful assessment, we've decided that we won't be
>   moving forward with a fix at this time. LinkedIn continuously
>   evaluates how features and products are used and we make adjustments
>   accordingly to focus our resources on providing the most value to our
>   members.
>
> We greatly appreciate your feedback and have documented the issue to
>   track additional reports of the problem and for consideration to be
>   addressed in a future release. If there's anything else I can help you
>   with, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: While LinkedIn's response is rather disappointing at least they confirm that it's a problem on their side – so thanks for sharing!

Comment: no problem, good luck further hopefully you can still continue.

Comment: can you share please th  linkedin response url

Comment: well, looks like the problem still exist... I have no idea how to fix this.
In every other social it works, only on LinkedIn is troublesome

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else dealing with similar - using NextJS through Cloudflare

Turned out it was because I restricted TLS>1.3, enabling 1.2 fixed it nice.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other people coming from Google, I was having this problem on my website as well, but for me the problem was HTML-minification related.

Linkedin doesn't parse the short doctype `<!doctypehtml>` so you'll probably get a 500 server error if this is in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but still seems to be a problem. I use NextJS/Vercel and I was getting the same error. I then set up my site through CloudFlare's edge proxy service and it started loading OG card previews--and quite fast. I highly recommend going through CloudFlare, it's free for most small websites and you get a lot of tools at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing some HTML comments that were being added to my page's HTML by a plugin after the closing  tag.  WP Super Cache's "Cache Status Messages" option to be precise.

Looks like LinkedIn want well-formed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem and found out that LinkedIn wants to parse clean HTML with no comments after/before HTML tags so my WordPress blog has an HTML compression plugin that is adding some HTML commented text `<!--HTML compressed, size saved 3%. From 128218 bytes, now 124376 bytes-->` after `</html>` that was causing the issue so I removed it and it's good to go. Check your page. So first try to validate your HTML and fix it on your end.