# Post Inspector (520 error), and how to debug?

Tags: metadata, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, cloudflare, meta

When I try to validate social sharing tags using Linked in Post Inspector I get the following error for any page I submit, but no other information, it gives no clue as to what is wrong:

[image]

I found this post:
[LinkedIn post inspector encountering server error on https URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173160/linkedin-post-inspector-encountering-server-error-on-https-url)

which says there are known issues with the Post Inspector, that post is over a year old is there really no update from Linked In on this?

I also found this:
[Validating link in post-inspector linkedin in gives server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332742/validating-link-in-post-inspector-linkedin-in-gives-server-error?rq=1)

I checked the certificate here:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

which reported that the hostname is correctly listed in the certificate.

Any advice on debugging this would be very welcome.

The 520 error seems to be related to Cloudflare, so this is possibly an issue with headers related to SSL - Cloudflare, certificate origin maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, finally.

I added the following changes to the web server config (as suggested by Cloudflare support):

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

limit_req zone=one burst=5
```

But this on it's own did not fix the issue, I also added some Cloud Flare Page Rules (which have sped up page loading), which did seem to fix the issue.

A final update from Cloudflare support is that the Page Rules would have reduced the number/size of cookies and so fixed the issue.