# Validating link in post-inspector linkedin in gives server error - Apache Shared Hosting Sub-Domains

Tags: apache, ssl, bitnami

Having an issue with LinkedIn and LinkedIn Post Inspector.

This issue is essentially the same as this previously posted [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332742/validating-link-in-post-inspector-linkedin-in-gives-server-error)

The server is configured to host multiple websites.

Response from lookup

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "HTTP_FETCH",
            "message": "We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL."
        }
    ],
    "urlRedirectTrail": {
        "trail": [
            {
                "url": "https://skills.*****.com",
                "httpStatus": 0
            }
        ],
        "lastModified": 1693207418166,
        "state": "BAD_RESPONSE",
        "key": "https://skills.******.com",
        "created": 1693207418166
    },
    "info": [],
    "warnings": []
}
```

I have the vhost.conf file setup like below.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerName skills.*****.com
  ServerAlias skills.*****.com
  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/star_*****_com_2023.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server_2023.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/DigiCertCA_2023.crt"
  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  DocumentRoot /home/Serveradmin/skills
  <Directory "/home/Serveradmin/skills">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
  H2Direct on
</VirtualHost>
```

The default SSL configuration file has the following. Which shows the SSLProtocols that match the other issue.

```
# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/star_*****_com_2023.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server_2023.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/DigiCertCA_2023.crt"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  <Location /server-status>
    Require local
    SetHandler server-status
  </Location>
  Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
  H2Direct on
</VirtualHost>
```

The web page serves as expected and contains the necessary OpenGraph tags.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

It shows the same information in the LinkedIn Post Inspector as it does on the DNS.org Open Graph Checker.
https://dnschecker.org/open-graph-preview-generate-metatags.php?query=